# How to store session first activity then how to get another activity?

Tags: android

1.intent session.storeinsession("alldetails",xml);

2.String xml1 = session.getFromSession("alldetails");

this code is wrong any one do this solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass data between activities on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-on-android)

Comment: Please write any code that you have already tried. Asking for ready to use solutions is not very useful at SO.